# Unable to locate an iframe element with the xpath expression

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am getting invalid Selector exception when I run

```
List<WebElement> allFrames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));
```

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unable to locate an
>   element with the xpath expression //iframe

I am using selenium 2.45.0 with java 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tag you don't need to use `//`

```
List<WebElement> allFrames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("iframe"));
```

Comment: I want to find all the iframes

Comment: It did not work.Everything works fine in chrome but i get this error for IE

Comment: @Guy, `XPath` expression `"tagName"` might be used instead of `"//tagName"` in case of searching for root `html` element. In current case `By.xpath("iframe")` will return an empty list

Comment: The code works for selenium 2.8.0 but for some reason it does not work on 2.45.0 for IE

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
List<WebElement> allFrames = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*//iframe"));
```

you can check below link for very useful xpath methods :

http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html